# помогите пожалуйста!!! цикл for

Tags: python, python-3.x, for

На вход программе подается три натуральных числа m, p,n:

m: стартовое количество организмов;
p: среднесуточное увеличение в %;
n: количество дней для размножения.
Напишите программу, которая предсказывает размер популяции организмов. Программа должна выводить размер популяции в каждый день, начиная с 1 и заканчивая n-м днем.

Формат входных данных

На вход программе подается три натуральных числа.

Формат выходных данных

Программа должна вывести текст в соответствии с условием задачи.

Sample Input 1:

> 10
> 50
> 6
> Sample Output 1:
>
> 1 10.0
> 2 15.0  3 22.5  4 33.75  5 50.625  6 75.9375

Comment: с чем вам помочь?

Comment: так, а с чем помочь? делаете цикл по дням и каждый новый день у вас должно быть `count *=  (1 + p / 100)` - только надо откинуть дробную часть через функцию floor

Comment: только при помощи for надо писать исходник

Comment: ну да, а что еще? правда согласитесь, что дробное число организмов - это бред :)

Comment: @ Zhihar согласен))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
m, p, n = float(input()), float(input()), int(input())
[print(i + 1, m * (1 + p / 100) ** (i)) for i in range(n)]
```

Comment: Был занят сорри, этот ответ для тех кто выеживался))) @Zhihar так норм?!

Comment: Да, так норм . .

Comment: мне препод выслал это но объяснять пока может подскажите как это работает!!! я совсем не понимаю умножение и равно что значить?

Comment: m, p, n = int(input()), int(input()), int(input())
for i in range(n):
    print(i + 1, m)
    m *= 1 + p / 100

Comment: судя по примеру автора, то конечно нет, не норм, ну посмотрите - ввод делает в одну строку, а у вас потребуется последовательный ввод трех чисел, и потом даже в примере есть логическая ошибка - какого фига дробное число микроорганизмов? этот как - немножко беременная?

Comment: я не знаю честно не понимаю что да как циклы только что начал учить(((

Answer (score 0):

```
m, p, n = int(input()), int(input()), int(input())
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    print(i, float(m))
    m += m * (p / 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
m, p, n = int(input()), int(input()), int(input())
for i in range(n):
   print(i + 1, m)
m *= 1 + p / 100
```

Comment: объясните ответ пожалуйста!!!

Comment: но это не ответ...

Comment: как?объсните !!!

Answer (score -6):

```
m, p, n = int(input()), int(input()), int(input())
d = m
for i in range(n):
    i += 1
    print(i, float(d))
    d += m / p
```

Comment: ошибка в вводе данных - ваш код не соответствует примеру

Comment: Во-первых код хорошо бы пояснять. А во-вторых автору вопроса хорошо бы хоть что-то сделать самому, не надо за него писать весь код, это его ничему не научит.

Comment: @CrazyElf, а в третьих код содержит критическую ошибку :)

Comment: я считаю иначе! Мне точно так же не помогали мол сам копай в итоге начинается остывание

Comment: все такие трушные как тогда правильно??? если что-то не устраивает оставьте свое мнение при себе я знаю что не правильно пусть сам копает дальше вот правильный подход по моему!!!!

Comment: @Егор, когда тебе дают домашку, а ты тут пишешь - сделайте мне задачу, то как вам это помогает изучать тему?

Comment: @Егор, и кроме того у вас совершенно неправильный код!!!!!!!!!!!!! чем вы этим кодом поможете автору?

Comment: ЛОЛ Я ЗНАЮ ЧТО НЕ ПРАВИЛЬНО !!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Егор эм, а зачем тогда пишите?

Comment: лол, и зачем вы его тогда приводите?

Comment: это мое дело что делать а что не делать !!!

Comment: `это мое дело что делать а что не делать !!!` т.е. своим неверным ответом вы вредите автору!!!

Comment: @Егор окей, но если вам запретят давать ответы, не жалуйтесь

Comment: да ради бога я хотя бы даю стимул что бы копал сам тоже а не строчу комменты!!!!

Comment: где вы здесь видите стимул что-то копать?

Comment: о боже кринжатура просто гипофиз просто не читай а старайся сам доделать покеда!

Comment: wtf?!  и что вы хотите с этим сказать?

Comment: Ну успокойтесь, что за коммьюнити?

Comment: @Zhihar ну и где вы молодой человек?!

Comment: @Егор, что-то требуется? :)

Comment: вы же умничали тут выше указал для вас ответ был занять объясните молодому человеку исходя от ваших препод навыков)))))

Comment: Это самый срачный вопрос за весь мой опыт на so. Давайте прекратим нести бред и закроем, наконец, этот вопрос

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115422/discussion-on-answer-by-----for).